# Reloading a page in angularjs application looses data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

**Background:**
I have a multi page angularjs application. I have a service factory object that I load with values in my initial page. The values loaded to the service factory object are available in the different views or pages via their corresponding controller js. The value provided by the user is lost if the user tries to do a browser refresh by clicking F5 button.

**My issue:**
When the application is loaded the 'loginView' is displayed, the userId and password entered by the user is passed to the second view (summaryView.html). And i can see the userId and password displayed correct in the second page. But if i refresh my second view (summaryView.html) then I loose all the values. The application is sort of reset.

I would like to retain the user supplied data even after the browser is refreshed or reloaded.

**My code:**

```
**index.html**

<div ng-app="offlineInspectionApp">
<div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script>
var mainApp = angular.module("offlineInspectionApp", ['ngRoute']);
mainApp.factory( 'AuthService', function() {
var userCore = {userId : "anonymous" , password: "password", status :"online"};
return {userCore: function() { return userCore; }};
});

mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/summary', {
templateUrl: 'summaryView.html',
controller: 'SummaryViewController'
}).
when('/login', {
templateUrl: 'loginView.html',
controller: 'LoginViewController'
});
}]);

**LoginViewController.js**

angular.module("offlineInspectionApp").controller('LoginViewController',  function($scope,$http,$location, AuthService) {
$scope.authenticateUser = function() {
AuthService.userCore.userId = $scope.userId;
AuthService.userCore.password = $scope.password;
$location.path( "/summary" );
}       
});

**SummaryViewController.js**

angular.module("offlineInspectionApp").controller('SummaryViewController',  function($scope,$http,$location, AuthService) {
$scope.syncInspectionDetails = function(inspectionId) {
alert(AuthService.userCore.userId +' '+ AuthService.userCore.password);
};

I have two html files 'loginView.html' and 'summaryView.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Flow

1- when the user enter the correct username and password you store the data in angular variables. this is fine and it redirect to summary page. `AuthService.userCore` has the same scope over the summery page so it displays the details on first attempt. 
2- when you refresh the page all the variable you declared in angularJs are cleared. So when you refresh the page you didn't get those variables.

Solution

there are two ways

1- either store the whole user data in cookie, and fetch the data from cookie on refresh.
2- one sign in complition use any access token and store it in cookie. And check for the access token and fetch the data from backend again on every refresh.